# Return the changed values after using fillna() python's pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I am using fillna() in a dataframe to change the null values from one column for another ones from another column, but I don't seem to find the way to print the changed values. I've tried to iterate over fillna() but that doesn't do the trick.

```
df.column_with_nan.fillna(column_to_use_as_nan_replacement, inplace=True)
```

I was thinking maybe I could run the new changed column against the old unchanged column, but I'd like to know whether there's a simpler way.

Any piece of advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any non-hacky way to straight print the changed values, but you can use [pandas.Series.compare()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.compare.html) to get the changed values. Just do

```py
tmp = pd.Series(df1.column_with_nan.copy())
df.row_with_nan.fillna(column_to_use_as_nan_replacement, inplace=True)
print(tmp.compare(df.column_with_nan))
```

You can also run df.compare for full dataframes.

Comment: I did not read your question carefully enough, you're running the fillna for just one row. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, that's my bad. I am running it for the whole column. I am going to edit my question :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but here's the updated answer.

Comment: Good to know, please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: Thanks again. I am totally new here. I had tried to used the arrow, but didn't work. I hadn't noticed the checked mark.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a mask before replacing the values:

```
mask = df["col_with_nan"].isna()
```

After replacing the nan values, you can then access the changed rows like this:

```
df[mask]
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col_with_nan": [np.nan, 1, 1, 1, np.nan, 1, 1, 1, np.nan],
        "column_to_use_as_nan_replacement": [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99],
    }
)
print(df)
mask = df["col_with_nan"].isna()
df.col_with_nan.fillna(df.column_to_use_as_nan_replacement, inplace=True)
print(df)
print(df[mask])
```